# JFileChooser on Mac doesn't return Files

Tags: java, swing, indexoutofboundsexception, jfilechooser

I try to use `JFileChooser` to get a `File` array which can contain files of .png or .svg data type. Besides that sometimes the window doesn't open, I don't get a result. If I want to work with the returned array I get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. The desired Behavior is that a JFrame will open and you can select one or more files from .svg or .png datatypes. The selected files, then should be saved in the Array files.

```
public class DataExplorer {

public static File[] start() {      

    FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Images ", "png", "svg");
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
    int returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        return fileChooser.getSelectedFiles();
    }

    else {
        System.out.println("Fail");
        return null;
    }
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws HeadlessException, Exception {        
    File[] file = start();
    System.out.println(file[0].getPath());

}
```

Comment: Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. You don't show how you invoke that method or how you display the result of the method.

Comment: File[] file = DataExplorer.start();
  System.out.println(file[0].getPath());

Comment: 1) Please don't put code in comments, where it is not easy to read. Instead [edit] the question to add the code. 2) Be sure to **read** the document linked by @camickr, since adding that single line of code to that question still does not make it an MCVE. 3) Make sure the GUI is started on the EDT. 4) Voting to close. (Please edit with MCVE soon.)

Comment: The solution is simple, I'm just waiting for you to post a proper "MCVE". We should be able to copy/paste/compile and test what you post. So you need a main() method. Creating a "MCVE" should be done for every question.

Comment: Sorry for that, I try to post it in the most simple way. Because there is stuff around that which definitely isn't the problem due to I use it in other Classes. I am very sorry I hope that this is now a proper "MCVE".

Comment: Now that is an "MCVE". I know I'm being picky but as you ask more complicated questions, the "MCVE" will force you to simplify the problem and most times you will find the answer even before you post. If not, then you just have simple code to post so we can test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return fileChooser.getSelectedFiles();
```

Check out the API for the `getSelectedFiles()` method?

It states:

> Returns a list of selected files if the file chooser is set to allow multiple selection.

I don't see where you set the file chooser to allow multiple selection.

So I'm guessing the array is not initialized if you don't allow for multiple selection.

You need to add:

```
fileChooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much! It works now, but unfortunately sometimes the Frame does not open. What could be the Problem here? Also the folder do react really bad on clicking. Sometimes I need to click 10 or more times before the folder opens. I am using OSX , could that be a Problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Tim, Glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: `Sometimes I need to click 10 or more times before the folder opens` - that is a different question and should be asked in a separate posting. `I am using OSX , could that be a Problem?` Could be. So the "MCVE" this time will need a dummy frame, with a JButton added to the frame and an ActionListener to display the dialog. Then people that use OSX can copy and test the code to see if they have the same problem. I use Windows 7 and don't have a problem. Maybe it will work better if you  pass the frame to your method so the dialog can be displayed with a parent frame instead of using null.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the complete example of setting to multiselect and getting the files.

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
chooser.showOpenDialog(frame or null);
File[] files = chooser.getSelectedFiles();
```

Comment: I don't use a frame. Do I have to overhand a frame to the showOpenDialog() frame? I now overhand "null".